# Creating the .exe file or .pkg file using jpackage command

Tags: installation, jar, exe, dmg, jpackage

I am trying to create a .pkg file for an java jar file so that application can be installed on the system. I want to ask user to provide the directory path where the files will be stored created by the application.
I am using the below command and need the help to check if user can apply path in installation wizard.

current command:

```
jpackage --name Test --input . --main-jar test.jar --type pkg --mac-package-identifier com.test.test.Test
```

I found the opetion --arguments if applied the main class args will be set need this option to be set by user at installation time.

```
jpackage --name Test --input . --main-jar test.jar --type pkg --mac-package-identifier com.test.test.Test --arguments /Documents
```

The /Documents should be replaced with user entered path on installation.